# How to Calculate Age in AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have birth_date, which function will let me subtract that from today's date?  Thank you

I tried DateDiff using NOW() but that didn't work.

I want to know the person's age as of today

Answer (score 2):

`dateDiff` function should work.  Make sure you are adding a calculated field in the data set and not in the analysis.

I was able to get the following to work fine:
`dateDiff({my_date},now())`

Make sure your birthday field is actually a time or date type and not a string.  If it is a string, you'll need to use the `parseDate` function to convert it to a date.

One thing to note is that `dateDiff` will return the difference in the number of days.  I am assuming this could be a very large number for most people so you may want `dateDiff({my_date},now())/365` to get an estimate of how many years old they are.